# JSON anonymous type property undefined?

Tags: javascript, json

in my mvc3 roject, I return the Json object:

```
 return Json(new { ID = guid, FileName = file.FileName, FullPath = filename });
```

then, in the JS code, I try to acces to the fields, e.g:

```
            onComplete: function (event, queueId, fileObj, response, data) {
                alert(response.ID); //test
            }
```

but i get the `undefined` message. If i just get the `alert(response);` I see the valid object:

```
{"ID":"22186ea1-a56a-45d1-9d13-d19f003dedf9","FileName":"file.txt","FullPath":"some_path"}
```

so how to access to that properties ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably seeing the JSON text that needs to be parsed into JavaScript data structures.

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(response);

alert( parsed.ID );
```

---

Without parsing it, you're trying to access the `ID` property of a `String` object.

```
var str = '{"ID":"22186ea1-a56a-45d1-9d13-d19f003dedf9","FileName":"file.txt","FullPath":"some_path"}';

alert( str.ID );  // undefined
```